# GWT Nothing shows up after changes

Tags: gwt, gwt-widgets

I am learning GWT Widget. I am having a simple `EntryPoint` class using which I am adding a Widget(ToggleButton). Initially it was working. Then I have just added the changes to change the attributes of my button. Then nothing came up in the specific HTML. I have done a clean-build too.

Below is my `onModuleLoad()`

```
@Override
public void onModuleLoad()
{
    // Create Instance for your Widget
    ToggleButton aToggleButton = new ToggleButton("Normal State", "Clicked State");

// Apply required style as per your wish
aToggleButton.setPixelSize(50, 10);
aToggleButton.setTitle("My first Simple Widget");

// Add it to the panel of your wish
RootPanel.get().add(aToggleButton);
}
```

Am I missing something. But I am sure that I haven't done anything apart from adding the lines that setting the size and title.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. compile to javascript, clean browser cache and try again.

Comment: Your code works. Did you add the script tag to the host page? Something like that? <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="yourProjectName/yourProjectName.nocache.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks El...My code works when i do everything from scratch and do... But  i had an Entrypoint which was working. Then i modified it in the above mentioned way.. But nothing shown up... Probably i have to try clearing the browser cache as suggested by @user905374.

Comment: @pecci will check the log...

Comment: @user905374 Clearing browser cache. Fixed the issue. Post it as the answer rather than comment. Solution need to be rewarded..;)

Comment: ok thanks, I added it as an answer, accept if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this code. Compile to javascript, clean browser cache and try again.